# SerializationInfo Replace Value (Cannot add the same member twice to a SerializationInfo object)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm attempting to override ISerializable.GetObjectData on a child class of a serializable object. I want to replace one of the values with my own value, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's what I tried.

```
public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    //replace the message value in info with my own value
    info.AddValue("Message", this.Message);
}
```

It throws an exception saying `"Cannot add the same member twice to a SerializationInfo object"`

Answer (score 1):

```
info.UpdateValue(name, value, type);
```

Note the warnings here though! https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/Serialization/SerializationInfo.cs#L358-L360

Note that this API doesn't exist in regular .NET, but since you're targeting .NET core you should be able to get away with it.

Comment: I tried this in code, but I get compiler errors. I have tried targeting both netcoreapp2.0 and netcorestandard2.0.

Here's the error: `"error CS1061: 'SerializationInfo' does not contain a definition for 'UpdateValue' and no extension method 'UpdateValue' accepting a first argument of type 'SerializationInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`

Comment: @TwitchBronBron huh; maybe that will only be available in 2.1; without that: you're SOL I'm afraid

Comment: Haha I guess so. Thanks for the info. I'll keep my eyes open for it in 2.1.